# How to change an ImageView from one activity from another activity?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-layout

I'm new in Android Programming and i want to ask some question

lets say that i have an ImageView in Activity A and i want to change the picture permanently from another Activity (Lets say that activity is Activity B). How can i accomplish that? i already tried to load the Imageview in Activity B and tried to change it but it always show me some NullPointer Exception, i already tried with load the intent and change the picture from the intent but it just last a while, when i open the Activity A again it back to the first image. Can someone help me? Thanks

this is what i tried so far :

Activity A :

```
 profil_pic = findViewById(R.id.profil_pic);
    profil_pic.setImageResource(getIntent().getIntExtra("myImageResource",R.drawable.aboutme));
```

Activity B :

```
Intent change_image = new Intent(HadiahActivity.this,ProfilActivity.class);
                            change_image.putExtra("myImageResource",R.drawable.dompet3);
                            startActivity(change_image);
                            finish();
```

Comment: Activity A starts before Activity B. right? so, you don't need to use Intent in Activity B. just make profil_pic `public static` and after that you can change it from Activity B :  A.profil_pic.setImageResource

Comment: this two differents activity are part of the main menu so user can access them randomly, and i already tested the setImageResources but it just change it temporary after i go back to the main menu and go to the activity A again it backs to the previous picture.  but, Thanks for the advice

Comment: you can use room to save every thing. for saving pictures you can convert image bitmap or uri to string and save that. another thing, remove profil_pic .setImageresource from class a. and set default pic randomly in xml file.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, i already solved it using shared preferences , and yes like what you said, i already convert my pic into bitmap and store it in the shared preferences, now i just need to configure the button , once again thank you :)